# Taking multiple lines of strings as command line input in Python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argv

In coding contests, I am supplied an initialization file from which to read initial parameters. However, sometimes the parameters are spread over separate lines as follows:

```
x
a 
b
```

(All of them integers)

Now when I read line1, I believe I would store `x` like this:

```
x = int(sys.argv[1])
```

How do I take care of other lines? Will `sys.argv[2]` give me the next parameter on line 2?

More precisely, will using:

```
par_list = sys.argv[1:].split(" ")
```

give me a list of parameters on all the lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
>> python program.py $(cat input.txt)
```

Sample program:

```
import sys
paras = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]
print(paras)
```

Sample input file:

```
42
-1
100
```

Output:

```
>> python program.py $(cat input.txt)
[42, -1, 100]
```

Comment: This only works in unix environments, and would not work on windows systems. @arvindch's answer should be the one accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're passing the input filename to the python script, in cmdline.

```
python script.py input.txt
```

In which case, `sys.argv[1] = 'input.txt'` is to access the contents of the input file:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Now, `lines` is a list containing all the lines of data from `input.txt`.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be what I was looking for. Thank you!